# How to switch between child routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I see my ProjectListContainer component when I open /projects. But nested links don't work (/projects/create). How can I solve it? I also need to switch nested components.

**This is my Router:**

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <RestrictedRouter path="/login" component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/logout" component={Logout} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/projects" component={Projects} />
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**This is my Component with nested switch:**

```
<div className={classes.content}>
    <Switch>
        <Route path={`${match.path}`} component={ProjectsListContainer} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/create`} component={CreateProject} />
        <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Kanban} />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

Comment: hey you want to use /projects/ for three route,Right?

Comment: yes. i wanna switch between child components depending on the entered url

Comment: like /projects/your_route.Right???

Comment: you are right, sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<div className={classes.content}>

        <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={ProjectsListContainer} />
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}/create`} component={CreateProject} />
        <Route exact path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Kanban} />
</div>
```

Comment: your solution gave me an idea

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    return (
    <div className={classes.content}>
          <Route path={`${match.path}`} component={ProjectsListContainer} />
          <Route path={`${match.path}/create`} component={CreateProject} />
          <Route path={`${match.path}/:id`} component={Kanban} />
     </div>);
```

ie without Switch.

or use `useRouteMatch`
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting

or Try

```
     let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
     <div className={classes.content}>
          <Route path={`${url}`} component={ProjectsListContainer} />
          <Route path={`${url}/create`} component={CreateProject} />
          <Route path={`${url}/:id`} component={Kanban} />
     </div>
```

Does above help?

Comment: it doesn't help me 'cause i need to switch between child components

Comment: i add "exact" w/o switch and it helps me. @vyas-arpit helps me